# how to filter products collection by updated_at field in descending order in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

> Actually i am trying to filter products using updated_at field in
>   magento 2?? but its not giving the result.If anyone have idea please help me.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setPageSize(4)
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_favour',1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', 'desc')->load();
```

Comment: Probably, you are trying to mix the concepts of **addFieldToFilter** and **order_by**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I think you want to sort product collection by `updated_at`)

try this -

```
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setPageSize(4)
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_favour',1)
                ->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->load();
```

Comment: Actually this line of code $collection->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc') is working fine using objectmanager in phtml file but its not working ib block file

Comment: share your block code

Comment: you need to inject  this file in your constructor `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` to use product collection

Comment: yes i injected Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection in constructor

Comment: its working actually there was a syntax error